# c# mvc simple identity manageemnt using GUID only

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, identity

I am working on an application that will verify a user via a GUID on the initial querystring and then read from cookie if this does not exist. There will actually be 2 GUIDs, one for them and one for their company and I will verify the user against both. The application stores no personal data and this 'validation' is purely to give permission to the user to access the site. My customer is adamant that they do not want a user to remember passwords etc.

I have been working on my own user class and am happy to use this, but would much rather use the build in identity management. Is there a way I can extend this and not force the user to authenticate using a password.

If the route I am taking with my own class is the best way forward, then can I add an object to session using the Session_Start event in global.asax and then access in my controllers.

Thanks for any advice on this.

Comment: Couldn't you use the GUID as a password and automatically use that so the user is unaware a password was entered?

Comment: Hadn't thought of that... but would still need userid which wouldn't be available.. customer doesn't want the user to type in a login screen of any kind